# does database partitioning require changes in application code?

Tags: database, oracle, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have an application written in Spring-boot , we have done with the optimization of the queries. We are thinking of database (Oracle database ) partitioning based on date. do we need to do any changes in our spring boot application or the oracle will handle things automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not *require* changes to the application.

However partitioning is not the magical "make everything go faster" switch.

To make partitioning work properly as a performance improvement, your queries **have** to include the partitioning key in their `where` clause - otherwise partitioning might even make things slower.

So, if you queries already include the partitioning key, you don't need to change anything.

If the queries do not include the partitioning key, you need to add them to all queries that should make use of partition pruning for performance purposes.

Comment: Actually the predicates do *not* have to be on the partition key; you will get pruning if you join on the partition key. For example, if you have a FACT table that is partition by date and you have a date dimension table that is join on the date column, then you would typically have predicates on the date dimension table. This would then create a bloom filter which would be pushed to the fact table, pruning the partitions.